# Llamar formulario de ayuda desde varios formularios y devolver valor

Tags: c#

Tengo un proyecto escrito en c# con tres formularios:
formulario01, 
formulario02,
formulario03 y todos tienen un boton que llamara al formularioAyuda.
El formularioAyuda devuelve una valor que debe ser recibido en el formulario que hizo la llamada.
Como puedo hacer para recibir el valor en cada formulario que hace la llamada?

Comment: xpajo, bienvenid@ a SOes. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el codigo con el cual estas intentanto resolver tu problema. Tambien echale un vistazo a los articulos: [ask] y [mcve] que te ayudaran bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es llamar a tu formulario de ayuda como un diálogo desde el formulario padre:

```
var ayuda = new Ayuda().ShowDialog();
```

Con esto en mente (y suponiendo que tienes un botón de acción en el formulario de ayuda) debes enviar un "resultado" del diálogo, claro que estableciendo como propiedades públicas las cosas que quieras devolver:

```cs
public string Valor1 { get; set; }
public DateTime Valor2 { get; set; }

private void btnOk_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    this.Valor1 = "Texto";
    this.Valor2 = DateTime.Now;

    // Aquí devuelves el resultado del "diálogo".
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

y finalmente lo recibes en el formulario padre:

```cs
private void btnAbrirAyuda_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    using(ayuda = new formularioAyuda())
    {
        var resultado = ayuda.ShowDialog();
        if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFormularioPadre.Text = ayuda.Valor1;
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo. No tuve que utilizar la linea: var ayuda = new Ayuda().ShowDialog(); Pero me funciona perfecto. Una cosa mas, como se llama ese thema que usas. Estoy usando VS2015.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado. Y si te fijas, la línea que mencionas tampoco la uso en el código de más abajo sino que la sustituyo con un `using(ayuda = new formularioAyuda())`. ¿A qué te refieres con "ese thema que usas"?

Comment: Hablo sobre los colores que tienes en el codigo del Visual Studio.